# Sin and Cos function incorrect in python

Tags: python, math, pygame

I am trying to make a top down shooter in pygame. I when I added the code to make the player move in the direction they are facing. The player would move in weird directions. This is the code I am using:

```
        if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_UP]:
            playerX = playerX - math.cos(playerFacing)
            playerY = playerY - math.sin(playerFacing)
        if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_DOWN]:
            playerX = playerX + math.cos(playerFacing)
            playerY = playerY + math.sin(playerFacing)
```

I tried just typing in math.cos(90) and it equaled -0.299515394756 but my calculator is telling me it equals 0. I am probably just making a stupid mistake, but can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong.
Thanks
Xeno

Comment: The math functions expect radians rather than degrees. Use `math.radians` to convert degrees to radians.

Answer (score 10):

`math.sin`, `math.cos`, etc. take angles in [radians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian).

You can use `math.radians` to convert degrees to radians. So:

```
math.sin(math.radians(90)) == 0
```

And you could just fix it in the posted snippet like that:

```
if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_UP]:
            playerX = playerX - math.cos(math.radians(playerFacing))
            playerY = playerY - math.sin(math.radians(playerFacing))
        if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_DOWN]:
            playerX = playerX + math.cos(math.radians(playerFacing))
            playerY = playerY + math.sin(math.radians(playerFacing))
```

However I advise to just use radians everywhere.

Comment: Beat me to it. :). But add some code for the guy, got to earn those points...

Comment: multiply your angle by (pi/180)

Answer (score 0):

`math.sin()` and `math.cos()` take angles in [Radians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian) and not in Degrees.

The same would be the case with `numpy.sin()` and `numpy.cos()`

```
>>> import math
>>> math.sin(90)
0.8939966636005579
>>> math.sin(1.57)
0.9999996829318346
```

You can see that `math.sin(90)` should be 1, but instead we get 0.89. But `math.sin(1.57)` gives us the correct answer, because 90 degrees is 1.57 in radians.

Here is a [WEBSITE](http://www.mathwarehouse.com/trigonometry/radians/convert-degee-to-radians.php) that explains you the conversion between **radians<-->degrees.**